# kendo-ui autocomplete extend

Tags: autocomplete, widget, kendo-ui, extend

I'm trying to extend the kendo-ui autocomplete control: I want the search start when te user hit enter, so basically I've to check the user input on keydown event.
I've tried to catch the keydown event with this code:

```
(function($) {
    ui = kendo.ui,
    Widget = ui.Widget
    var ClienteText = ui.AutoComplete.extend({
        init: function(element,options) {
            var that=this;
            ui.AutoComplete.fn.init.call(this, element, options);                
            $(this).bind('keydown',function(e){ console.log(1,e); });
            $(element).bind('keydown',function(e){ console.log(2,e); });
        },
        options: {
            [...list of my options...]
        },
        _keydown: function(e) {
            console.log(3,e);
            kendo.ui.AutoComplete.fn._keydown(e);
        }
    });
    ui.plugin(ClienteText);
})(jQuery);
```

None of the binded events gets called, only the _keydown, and then I'm doing something wrong and cannot call the autocomplete "normal" keydown event.
I've seen a lot of examples that extend the base widget and then create a composite widget, but I'm not interested in doing that, I only want to add a functionality to an existing widget.
Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Doing this in the init function:
`$(element).bind('keydown',function(e){
    var kcontrol=$(this).data('kendoClienteText');
    if (e.which === 13) {
        kcontrol.setDataSource(datasource_clientes);
        kcontrol.search($(this).val());
    } else {
        kcontrol.setDataSource(null);
    }
});`
actually do what I want, but I'm not sure this is the correct way to do it. Any suggestion is welcome! (sorry for the code formatting)

Comment: I still don't see in your code how you stopping the "offical" kendo autocomplete control search call ?

Comment: the $(element).bind('keydown',function(e){...}) do the magic, i'll put the code that is actually working in an answer at bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code actually work:

```
  (function($) {
    ui = kendo.ui,
    ClienteText = ui.AutoComplete.extend({
      init: function(element,options) {
        ui.AutoComplete.fn.init.call(this, element, options);                
        $(element).bind('keydown',function(e){
          var kcontrol=$(this).data('kendoClienteText');
          if (e.which === 13) {
            kcontrol.setDataSource(datasource_clientes);
            kcontrol.search($(this).val());
          } else {
            kcontrol.setDataSource(null);
          }
        });
      },
      options: {
        name: 'ClienteText',
      }
    });
    ui.plugin(ClienteText);
  })(jQuery);
```

but I don't know if it's the correct way to do it.

Comment: FYI... when first tried this, I got "maximum call stack size exceeded". It turns out that I forgot the 'options' block. HTH someone else.

Answer (score 2):

What about avoiding the extend and take advantage of build in options and methods on the existing control : http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/Vttyq/1/

```
//create AutoComplete UI component
 var complete = $("#countries").kendoAutoComplete({
     dataSource: data,
     filter: "startswith",
     placeholder: "Select country...",
     separator: ", ",
     minLength: 50 // this is to be longer than your longest char
 }).data("kendoAutoComplete"); 

 $("#countries").keypress(function (e) {
     if (e.which == 13) {
         complete.options.minLength = 1; // allow search
         complete.search($("#countries").val());
         complete.options.minLength = 50; // stop the search again
     }
 });
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but in this case I've to create a keypress function for all controls, or aggregate a class and then do a $('.myclass').keypress etc etc, I want to have extend a control because, for example, not only I want to do $('#myinput').myControl() and have the possibility to have a complex control writing the code inside the control, not outside.